# Errors when using g.drawImage() in Java

Tags: java, image

I have been stumped on why I'm getting the following error:

```
TicTacToeClient.java:128: error: cannot find symbol                  
g.drawImage(icon, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);  
symbol:   variable icon  
location: class TicTacToeClient

TicTacToeClient.java:131: error: cannot find symbol                        
g.drawImage(opponentIcon, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);  
symbol:   variable opponentIcon  
location: class TicTacToeClient
```

This is the whole code for reference:

```
package Group9;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToeClient {

public JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
public Painter painter;
public final int Width = 506;
public final int Height = 527;

public Image field;
public Image redX;
public Image blueX;
public Image redCircle;
public Image blueCircle;

public static JTextField T1; //Player 1 - Points
public static JTextField T2; //Player 2 - Points
public static JTextField T3; //Status of the game - Connected Etc

public static int xMouse;
public static int yMouse;
public static int Clicked;
public char mark;

public String[] Square = new String[9];

public static int ServerPort;
public Socket Sock;
public BufferedReader in;
public PrintWriter out;

public TicTacToeClient(String ServerAddress) throws Exception {

    //Setup networking
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input the Server's Port number: ");
    int ServerPort = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    Sock = new Socket(ServerAddress, ServerPort);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Sock.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(Sock.getOutputStream(), true);

    //Text Boxes
        //Text Field 1 -- Display Player 1 score &  JTextField(5) -> Create text thing that is 5 characters long
    T1 = new JTextField(20);
    T1.setBounds(100,40,110,30);
    painter.add(T1);

        //Text Field 2 - Display Player 2 score
    T2 = new JTextField(20);
    T2.setBounds(400,40,110,30);
    painter.add(T2);

        //Text Field 3 - The purpose is to show the user what mode he's connected to and if he's currently playing or not
    T3 = new JTextField(20);
    T3.setBounds(235,10,130,30);
    painter.add(T3);

    //Buttons:
        //Button 1
    JButton B1 = new JButton("QUIT GAME(orsomethingelse)");
    B1.setBounds(30,10,200,30);
    painter.add(B1);
        //Button 2
    JButton B2 = new JButton("RESET GAME");
    B2.setBounds(370,10, 200, 30);
    painter.add(B2);

    //Button Actions:
    B1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            out.println("QUIT");
            T3.setText("Opponent disconnected");
        }
    });

}//End TicTacToeClient(String ServerAddress)

private void loadImages() {
    try {
        ImageIcon temp = new ImageIcon("/board.png");
        field = temp.getImage();
        temp = new ImageIcon("/redX.png");
        redX = temp.getImage();
        temp = new ImageIcon("/redCircle.png");
        redCircle = temp.getImage();
        temp = new ImageIcon("/blueX.png");
        blueX = temp.getImage();
        temp = new ImageIcon("/blueCircle.png");
        blueCircle = temp.getImage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void play() throws Exception {

    int lengthOfSpace = 160;
    String response;

    Graphics g;
    g.drawImage(field,60,40,null);

    try {
        response = in.readLine();

        if (response.startsWith("Welcome")) {
            char mark = response.charAt(49);
            Image icon = (mark == 'X') ? blueX : redCircle;
            Image opponentIcon  = (mark == 'X') ? redX : blueCircle;
            T3.setText(response);
        }//End if(response.startsWith("Welcome"))

        while (true) {
            response = in.readLine();

            if (response.startsWith("VALID_MOVE")) {
                int i = 1 + Integer.parseInt(response.substring(11));
                if (mark == 'X') {
                    g.drawImage(icon, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                }
                else if (mark == 'O') {
                    g.drawImage(opponentIcon, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                    T3.setText(response);
                }
                frame.repaint();
                T3.setText("Opponent's Turn");
            } else if (response.startsWith("OPPONENT_MOVED")) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(15));
                if (mark == 'X') {
                    g.drawImage(icon, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                }
                else if (mark == 'O') {
                    g.drawImage(opponentIcon, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                    T3.setText(response);
                }
                frame.repaint();
                T3.setText("Your Turn");
            } else if (response.startsWith("VICTORY")) {
                T3.setText("You win!");
                break;
            } else if (response.startsWith("DEFEAT")) {
                T3.setText("You lose!");
                break;
            } else if (response.startsWith("TIE")) {
                T3.setText("You tied!");
                break;
            } else if (response.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                T3.setText(response.substring(8));
            }
            painter.repaint();

        }//End while(true)

        out.println("QUIT");
    }//End try
    finally {
        Sock.close();
    }//End finally

}//End play()

class Painter extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Painter() {
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }//End Painter()

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }//End paintComponent(Graphics g)

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Clicked++;

        out = new PrintWriter(Sock.getOutputStream(), true);

        String temp = String.valueOf(mark);

        out.write("Total Clicks: " + Clicked);

        int xMouse = e.getX() / 160;
        int yMouse = e.getY() / 160;
        int i = 0;

        if ((xMouse > 49) && (xMouse < 210) && (yMouse > 99) && (yMouse < 250)) {
            i = 1;
            Square[i] = temp;
            out.write("MOVE" + i);
        }
        else if ((xMouse > 211) && (xMouse < 390) && (yMouse > 99) && (yMouse < 250)) {
            i = 0;
            Square[i] = temp;
            out.write("MOVE" + i);
        }
        else if ((xMouse > 391) && (xMouse < 551) && (yMouse > 99) && (yMouse < 250)) {
            i = 1;
            Square[i] = temp;
            out.write("MOVE" + i);
        }
        else if ((xMouse > 49) && (xMouse < 210) && (yMouse > 251) && (yMouse < 450)) {
            i = 2;
            Square[i] = temp;
            out.write("MOVE" + i);
        }
        else if ((xMouse > 211) && (xMouse < 390) && (yMouse > 251) && (yMouse < 450)) {
            i = 3;
            Square[i] = temp;
            out.write("MOVE" + i);
        }
        else if ((xMouse > 391) && (xMouse < 551) && (yMouse > 251) && (yMouse < 450)) {
            i = 4;
            Square[i] = temp;
            out.write("MOVE" + i);
        }
        else if ((xMouse > 49) && (xMouse < 210) && (yMouse > 450) && (yMouse < 601)) {
            i = 5;
            Square[i] = temp;
            out.write("MOVE" + i);
        }
        else if ((xMouse > 211) && (xMouse < 390) && (yMouse > 450) && (yMouse < 601)) {
            i = 6;
            Square[i] = temp;
            out.write("MOVE" + i);
        }
        else if ((xMouse > 391) && (xMouse < 551) && (yMouse > 450) && (yMouse < 601)) {
            i = 7;
            Square[i] = temp;
            out.write("MOVE" + i);
        }

    }//End mousePressed(MouseEvent e)

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //Not needed
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //Not needed
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        //Not needed
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        //Not needed
    }

}//End class Painter

private boolean wantsToPlayAgain() {
    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                                                 "Want to play again?",
                                                 "Tic Tac Toe is Fun Fun Fun",
                                                 JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    frame.dispose();
    return response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
}

public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please input the Server's IP Address: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ServerIP = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please input the Server's Port number: ");
        int ServerPort = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        TicTacToeClient client = new TicTacToeClient(ServerIP);
        //Layout GUI
        loadImages();
        client.painter = new Painter();
        client.painter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Width, Height));
        client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.frame.setSize(700, 750);
        client.frame.setVisible(true);
        client.frame.setResizable(false);
        client.play();
        if (!client.wantsToPlayAgain()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}


}//End class TicTacToeClient
```

The part of the code that it's referencing is this:

```
public void play() throws Exception {

    int lengthOfSpace = 160;
    String response;

    Graphics g;
    g.drawImage(field,60,40,null);

    try {
        response = in.readLine();

        if (response.startsWith("Welcome")) {
            char mark = response.charAt(49);
            Image icon = (mark == 'X') ? blueX : redCircle;
            Image opponentIcon  = (mark == 'X') ? redX : blueCircle;
            T3.setText(response);
        }//End if(response.startsWith("Welcome"))

        while (true) {
            response = in.readLine();

            if (response.startsWith("VALID_MOVE")) {
                int i = 1 + Integer.parseInt(response.substring(11));
                if (mark == 'X') {
                    g.drawImage(icon, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                }
                else if (mark == 'O') {
                    g.drawImage(opponentIcon, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                    T3.setText(response);
                }
                frame.repaint();
                T3.setText("Opponent's Turn");
            } else if (response.startsWith("OPPONENT_MOVED")) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(15));
                if (mark == 'X') {
                    g.drawImage(icon, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                }
                else if (mark == 'O') {
                    g.drawImage(opponentIcon, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                    T3.setText(response);
                }
                frame.repaint();
                T3.setText("Your Turn");
            } else if (response.startsWith("VICTORY")) {
                T3.setText("You win!");
                break;
            } else if (response.startsWith("DEFEAT")) {
                T3.setText("You lose!");
                break;
            } else if (response.startsWith("TIE")) {
                T3.setText("You tied!");
                break;
            } else if (response.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                T3.setText(response.substring(8));
            }
            painter.repaint();

        }//End while(true)

        out.println("QUIT");
    }//End try
    finally {
        Sock.close();
    }//End finally

}//End play()
```

Comment: What if `response.startsWith("Welcome")` is `false`? What will the value of `icon` and `opponentIcon` be? You need to declare these variables outside the if-block and assign them a value for all cases.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: You might also find [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) worth a read

Comment: `Graphics g;` followed by `g.drawImage(field,60,40,null);` will generate a `NullPointerException`. You could a wash with thread violations and questionable implementations

Answer (score 0):

You create your variable `icon` in `if` statement so scope of this var is only inside `if`.
You should create them before `if`, somewhere inside your `play()` method.
The error message is also quite obvious: `TicTacToeClient.java:128: error: cannot find symbol ... variable icon`. For more information and for better understanding read about 'variable scope'.